# Testing if connected rows in a table are really connected

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with two columns that are sometimes paired by their ID's. I would like to check if up to now I've done everything right and the connected entries are correctly connected. The table looks something like this:

```
ID | (...) | partnerID
======================
 1 | (...) |     5 
 2 | (...) |     3 
 3 | (...) |     2 
 4 | (...) |     7 
 5 | (...) |     1 
 6 | (...) |    null
 7 | (...) |     4
 8 | (...) |    null
```

Is there a way to check with a query if the connections are all there? Something like `"for all partnerIDs check if their partnerIDs are this ID"`?

My knowledge of SQLite is really basic, so I'm not even sure what exactly to google for. It would be great if some of you could help me out.

If it is simply not possible a "no" would be great as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the partner for each row, join the table with itself:

```
SELECT p1.ID,
       p2.ID
FROM MyTable AS p1
JOIN MyTable AS p2 ON p1.partnerID = p2.ID;
```

To find the partner's partner, add another join:

```
SELECT p1.ID,
       p2.ID,
       p3.ID
FROM MyTable AS p1
JOIN MyTable AS p2 ON p1.partnerID = p2.ID
JOIN MyTable AS p3 ON p2.partnerID = p3.ID;
```

You can now check whether `p1` and `p3` match:

```
SELECT p1.*,
       p2.*
FROM MyTable AS p1
JOIN MyTable AS p2 ON p1.partnerID = p2.ID
JOIN MyTable AS p3 ON p2.partnerID = p3.ID
WHERE p1.ID != p3.ID;
```

All these joins ignore rows with NULLs (without matches).
To catch wrong partnerships where one direction is NULL, make the second join an outer join:

```
SELECT p1.*,
       p2.*
FROM MyTable AS p1
JOIN MyTable AS p2 ON p1.partnerID = p2.ID
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS p3 ON p2.partnerID = p3.ID
WHERE p1.ID IS NOT p3.ID;
```